# Polyglossia \setotherlanguage french breaks autospacing

Tags: spacing, luatex, polyglossia, french

I'm writing a German (main), French paper with lua and polyglossia. After I use a local French `\textfrench{}` or `\begin{french}` - `\end{french}` the French punctuation spacing continues, even in a German env, e.g. so: instead of so: -- so(space):

I am not sure if this is a bug or if I made a mistake somewhere. I also tried it for English/French, same problem. Thanks for any help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{french}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Das ist ein simpler Test: test im Test? Test! oder so.

\textfrench{so!}

so: oder so?

\begin{french}
oder so? so! oder:
\end{french}

Das ist ein simpler Test: test im Test? Test! oder so.

\textgerman{so! oder?}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can reproduce this issue with version 1.44 of  `polyglossia`. The recently released v1.45 seems to have resolved it. You should think about an update.

Comment: There were various reports about this and related issues at the `polyglossia` bugtracker: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/66, https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/68, https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/49, https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/201. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/186156/35864.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report and the issue has been solved in version 1.45 of polyglossia

Comment: thanks for the quick answers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing language back and forth with polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186156/changing-language-back-and-forth-with-polyglossia)