# expand \today in english rather than hindi

Tags: fonts, xetex, languages, scripts

```
  \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \usepackage[Latin,Devanagari]{ucharclasses}
    \setmainfont{Mangal}
    \newfontfamily{\devanagarifont}{Mangal}
    \newfontfamily{\englishfont}[Ligatures=TeX]{Garamond}
    \setmainlanguage{hindi}
    \setotherlanguage{english}
    \setTransitionsFor{Latin}
      {\hyphenrules{english}\englishfont}
      {\hyphenrules{hindi}\devanagarifont}
    \setTransitionsFor{Devanagari}
      {\hyphenrules{hindi}\devanagarifont}
      {\hyphenrules{english}\englishfont}
    \begin{document}
    \today 
    आज सोमवार है 
    \end{document}
```

I would like \today to expand to 19-04-2021 or 19 April 2021 rather than 19 एप्रिल 2021 which happens when I use hindi as main language. But if I choose english as main language, the hindi is not typeset automatically without specifying it as \hindi
I do not want this either.
Kindly help

Comment: would `\textenglish{\today}` be ok, or do you want to be able to provide only `\today` and make the switch to English automatic?

Comment: `\NewCommandCopy\todayORIG\today\renewcommand\today{\textenglish{\todayORIG}}`.

Comment: Both these suggestions does not seem to be working for me. Nothing typeset.

Comment: Did you try with exactly the example code that you posted (and nothing more)? Are there any errors in the log file? I can't test with Garamond because I don't have that font, but with a different Latin font it works ok when I try it.

Comment: Does `\begin{english} \today \end{english}` not work for you? (See also this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186174/118712 )

Comment: @MarkusG. Though \begin{english} \today \end{english} will work, I will have to change it in hundreds of document. so I can change input file only {Preamble}

Comment: So, your question is not actually: How do I expand `\today` in english, but rather: How do I write a multilingual document in both english and hindi, typesetting both mixed without telling latex which is which?

Comment: @MarkusG. No! :-). I just want to redefine \today in preamble, so users do not have to bother. They can just write \today as usual.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/593963

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is slightly more complicated than it might appear. You can redefine the `\today` macro in the preamble to always print the date in English, but `polyglossia` changes that back at `\begin{document}` to use the current language.

To solve this issue you can do the redefinition using `\AfterEndPreamble` from the `etoolbox` package, which is performed at the end of `\begin{document}`, so after the redefinition by `polyglossia`.

The version in the comment by Skillmon `\NewCommandCopy\todayORIG\today` works in LaTeX versions of October 2020 or newer. If you have an older version you can use `\LetLtxMacro` from the package `letltxmacro`.

Note that you need to put the redefinition line **after** `\usepackage{polyglossia}`, otherwise it does not work. So:

```
\LetLtxMacro{\todayORIG}{\today}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\AfterEndPreamble{\renewcommand\today{\textenglish{\todayORIG}}}
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\todayORIG}{\today}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\AfterEndPreamble{\renewcommand\today{\textenglish{\todayORIG}}}
\usepackage[Latin,Devanagari]{ucharclasses}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\newfontfamily{\devanagarifont}{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}[Ligatures=TeX]{DejaVu Serif}
\setmainlanguage{hindi}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setTransitionsFor{Latin}
   {\hyphenrules{english}\englishfont}
   {\hyphenrules{hindi}\devanagarifont}
\setTransitionsFor{Devanagari}
   {\hyphenrules{hindi}\devanagarifont}
   {\hyphenrules{english}\englishfont}

\begin{document}
\today 

आज सोमवार है 
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

<sub>(note that it is not actually Monday today, but ok)</sub>