# Why hindi is not getting typeset in this example?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, languages, ucharclasses

```
\documentclass[12pts, a4paper, twocolumn, columnsep= 4 mm]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, polyglossia}
\usepackage[Devanagari]{ucharclasses}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\setTransitionTo{Devanagari}{\fontspec[Script=Devanagari]{Nirmala UI}}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\begin{document}
Calibri is english font 
Nirmala UI is हिन्दी font 
\end{document}
```

Both calibri and Nirmala UI are available in Windows as default available fonts. But somehow fontspec is not typesetting hindi हिन्दी , while english is correctly typeset. Xelatex is not showing any warning/error.

I  would like to have a solution which does not depend upon language changing command.
Kindly help

Comment: This code will work if I set \setmainlanguage{hindi}, and \setotherlanguage{english}. But it  will fail to work, if main language is set be english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using a class you need to use its class command. Also
for some reason, \fontspec doesn't work there. But you can define a new font family.

```
\documentclass[12pts, a4paper, twocolumn, columnsep= 4 mm]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, polyglossia,color}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\newfontfamily\devafont{Nirmala UI}[Script=Devanagari]
\setTransitionsForDevanagari{\devafont}{\normalfont}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\begin{document}

Calibri is english font
Nirmala UI is हिन्दी font

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer! You should add \setmainlanguage{english} \setotherlanguage{hindi} so that xelatex do not show warning.